# Ended bounty questions are not being removed from the Featured tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounty

I'm not sure if this is related to the network wide bug [Questions with ended bounties are not being removed from the "featured" tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/281760/242209), but my former bounty question [What was Nintendo's Software Development Environment for NES Games?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/1135/621) is still visible in the featured tab for me.

[image: Bounty Question]

Is this intentional or a bug?

Comment: I originally thought it was cache-related, but as it appears for other people it might be a faulty cron job.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks; there was a bug on the "tag engine" (the backend system that deals with this stuff) that failed to update the "count" of an index when that index was being reduced to zero (it is fine when reducing in general - just the zero case is the problem). This meant it was happily reporting data that it *knew* wasn't "featured" (or whatevever) any more. Essentially (not the actual code!):

```
// rebuild a filtered+sorted index...
int matches = workspace.ApplyFilter();
if(matches == 0) {
     // nothing to do
} else {
    workspace.ApplySort();
    index.UpdateCountAndCopyFromWorkspace(matches , workspace);
}
```

In the zero case, it would never actually mark the index as being empty (the "nothing to do" was wrong - it should still have updated the count). Entirely my fault. A permanent fix for this will deploy today.

Comment: Thanks!  Is this a network-wide issue, or just an issue on retroconputing?

Comment: @JAL it was everywhere, but it would only be *observed* if there was a site with an index that was changing from non-empty to empty, most commonly because the last "featured" question expired or was awarded. That means we wouldn't expect  to see it on sites like stackoverflow, because that *just  would never happen*

Comment: Thanks Marc for your detailed answer!

Comment: You missed the [MSE bug report about it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281760/questions-with-ended-bounties-are-not-being-removed-from-the-featured-tab). Unless it's not the same thing?

Comment: @ShadowWizard ta; JAL found it for me :)